# Regex to operate after two conditions

Tags: regex, perl, sed, awk

Hey guys this should be simple, I'm just not seeing it, I would like to create a regex (workable under PERL, Awk, SED / *nix) that will operate after it find a leading Cash ($), the very next Equal (=) and work on what is between either the first instance of double or single quotes to the last instance of double or single quotes.

Let me set up a few examples.

```
$this = 'operate on some text in here'; # operates between single quotes
$this = "operate on some text in here"; # operates between double quotes
$this = 'operate "on some text" in here'; # operates between single quotes
$this = 'operate \'on some text\' in here'; # operates between outer single quotes
```

I tried some really bad regex. but just couldn't get it to match right.

Here's what I'm inserting it into, in case anyones interested

```
printf '$request1 = "select * from whatever where this = that and active = 1 order by something asc";\n' |
grep '{regex}' * |
perl -pe 's/select/SELECT/g ; s/from/\n   FROM/g ; s/where/\n      WHERE/g ; s/and/\n      AND/g ; s/order by/\n         ORDER BY/g ; s/asc/ASC/g ; s/desc/DESC/g ;' | ## enter through file with all clauses
awk '{gsub(/\r/,"");printf "%s\n%d",$0,length($0)}' ## take first line convert to whitespace, use on following lines
```

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Script:***

```
@list = <main::DATA>;

foreach (@list) {
  my @x = /^\s*\$(\S+)\s*=\s*(['"])((?:.(?!\2)|\\\2)*.?)\2\s*;/;
  $x[2] =~ s/\\$x[1]/$x[1]/g; # remove backslash before quote character
  print "$x[0]\t$x[2]\n";
}

__DATA__
$this = 'operate on some text in here';     // operates between single quotes
$this = "operate on some text in here";     // operates between double quotes
$this = 'operate "on some text" in here';   // operates between single quotes
$this = 'operate \'on some text\' in here'; // operates between outer single quotes
```

***will give you:***

```
this   operate on some text in here
this   operate on some text in here
this   operate "on some text" in here
this   operate 'on some text' in here
```

Comment: I wouldn't want this or whatever other var is prior to quotes though, up for a damned good answer

Comment: @ehime - if you want just right site of equation, then change `print` to `"$x[2]\n"` only.

Comment: @ehime - `@list = <STDIN>;` and remove all `__DATA__` block

Comment: when doing this though it erases all other text in the file not meeting the requirements

Answer (score 5):

Generally, if you're parsing actual perl code, I'd suggest (and use) [PPI](https://metacpan.org/module/PPI).  Otherwise, just use [Regexp::Common](https://metacpan.org/module/Regexp%3a%3aCommon)

```
use Regexp::Common;

my @lines = split /\s*\n\s*/, <<'TEST';
$this = 'operate on some text in here'; // operates between single quotes
$this = "operate on some text in here"; // operates between double quotes
$this = 'operate "on some text" in here'; // operates between single quotes
$this = 'operate \'on some text\' in here'; // operates between outer single quotes
TEST

for (@lines)
{
    /$RE{quoted}{-keep}/ && print $1, "\n";
}
```

Gives:

```
$ perl x.pl
'operate on some text in here'
"operate on some text in here"
'operate "on some text" in here'
'operate \'on some text\' in here'
```

Comment: @ZnArK - if you're going to "fix" my code, test your fix first. It wasn't even close to producing correct output.  You'll also notice that I showed the output from the original code, which shows there is no bug in the code.  (Those that approved your edit also did not test it.)  I've been forced to revert it to keep it correct.

Comment: @Tanktalus I wasn't debugging your code for you, only fixing the comments so that it would be formatted correctly.   Is `//` correct comment markup for perl?

Comment: @Tanktalus I see now why this works.  Guess prettify doesn't interpret perl correctly....

Comment: @user1215106 I didn't want the opening/closing quotation characters, no.

Comment: @user1215106 because its not that hard to strip the quotes from his method, and its a fairly flexible approach

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
 sed 's/\(\$[^=]*=[^'\''"]*\)\(['\''"]\)[^\\'\''"]*\(\\['\''"][^'\''"]*\)*\2/\1\2Replacement\2/' file
```